# Axis2 Options: setAction()

Tags: java, http, client, apache-axis

I've successfully managed to create a HTTP Basic Authentication Client.

There is a particular operation that I'm having some doubts as to it's purpose.

I tried a tutorial for a simple helloworld script and some other tutorials are the internet and I saw this:

```
options.setAction("urn:echo");
```

If I comment this line of code, the client works anyway.

So what does it do? I can't find specific information about this.

I know that my service has an "echo" operation.

So if I had both an "echo" and "echo2" operations, I would have to call setAction for each one?

Regards,
Nuno.

Answer (score 2):

This is the soapAction attribute in wsdl binding for operation element. If nothing is specified in the WSDL then its value should be blank string or the exact value mentioned in the WSDL should be used here.
Its purpose is not very well defined but it can be used for filtering the traffic.